# Xml parsing in a specific format and then searching and listing all the occurrence of any values

Tags: vb.net, vba, xml-parsing

my requirement is as follows:
1= read an xml url and then search a specific value using a text box and then list all the occurrence of that text in parsed order

For eg: my API is as follows:

```
<Record1>
<ID>4</ID>
<Name>ABCD</Name>
<NumberOfPosition>1</NumberOfPosition>
<Rate>0</Rate>
<SignalID>102288301</SignalID>
<SignalTime>2013-07-16T23:59:59.043</SignalTime>
<SignalType>CloseMarketOrder</SignalType>
<Loss>0</Loss>
<SubName>78730843</SubName>
<SystemID>720</SystemID>
<SystemName>Passion 1</SystemName>
<Profitrate>0</Profitrate>
</Record1>

<pre lang="HTML"><blockquote class="FQ"><div class="FQA">Quote:</div><Record2>
<ID>4</ID>
<Name>ABCD</Name>
<NumberOfPosition>1</NumberOfPosition>
<Rate>0</Rate>
<SignalID>102288301</SignalID>
<SignalTime>2013-07-16T23:59:59.043</SignalTime>
<SignalType>CloseMarketOrder</SignalType>
<Loss>0</Loss>
<SubName>78730843</SubName>
<SystemID>720</SystemID>
<SystemName>Passion 1</SystemName>
<Profitrate>0</Profitrate>
</Record2>
```

and so on

I want to parse it like:

```
ID = 4
Name = ABCD
```

etc

and then search using a text box for eg: `Name = ABCD` so this search should check the all the occurrence  of ABCD in the `xml` and list the complete data related to the ABCD value in the `text box`

Plese help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code goes like this for me. See if it can help you. :-)

```
    dim strID as string = '1' ''Your ID 
    Dim xmlDoc As New XmlDocument

    xmlDoc.Load(PATH) 'Load Xml here

    For Each node As XmlNode In xmlDoc.ChildNodes
       for each subNode as XmlNode in node
          if sunNode.innerText = strID then
             'get all the sub node details
             'Exit both the for loops

          End If
       next
    Next
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but in xmlDoc.Load(PATH) is i enter url is not working and clues ? as i hve to pass direct url not xml file

Comment: you can not enter url there. you can use server.mappath there. or else you need to check if there is any other way to load xml from the server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i asked how to search a string and then print the result of complete data matching that string 
For eg: in the above example 
if i search for ABCD then it should result all data related to ABCD abd if suppose ABC is occuring many times in the xml then also all the relavent data should be printed in the text box

Please help